# custom styled tiles for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

How do i go about creating live tiles with custom font and styles as done by the guys in the sticky notes HD app? . I searched a lot but found only how to create tiles using the default three templates . Here is a screenshot from their app page . I would like to achieve custom tiles like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is all done by creating images and via rendering XAML controls into images.

If you don't want your user to see tile before pinning (in case you would want to allow them to customize it) you need to create these tiles in code. It is usually `Grid` with `TextBlock` controls.

Rendering is done with `WriteableBitmap` class. You create instance, specify size:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(200, 200);

            wb.Render([XAML control to render], null);
            wb.Invalidate();
```

Now you just need to save it into isolated storage (it needs to be in "/Shared/ShellContent/" folder) and set it as background for your tile.

EDIT: No background usually means that your file path is wrong. 
Try this:

```
fp.BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/img1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Those images aren't delete automatically. You can track tiles with `ShellTile.ActiveTiles` and check `NavigationUri` property. To determine if image can be deleted.